# Send UrlEncodedForm data using euc-jp in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x, urlencode, cjk

I am wondering how I can send form data using euc-jp encoding. My attempt at encoding below is still sending japanese text as ? and odd characters. Thank you!

This is how I am currently doing it (not working properly):

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://httpbin.org/post");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Testing", "雄大"));
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, forName("EUC-JP")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems good to me. `httpbin.org` doesn't seem to be handle EUC-JP in response. Instead you can use `putsreq.com` to see your request parameters.

```java
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Create new PutsReq URL by yourself
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://putsreq.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Testing", "雄大"));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, Charset.forName("euc-jp")));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
    while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println (reader.readLine());
    }
    reader.close();
  }
}
```

And you will see

```
Testing=%CD%BA%C2%E7
```

in the inspect page. `0xCDBA` means `雄` in EUC-JP.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found the issue. I was reading input from a file that was not encoded with euc-jp.